# TinyFCK not inserting image URL once image selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce

I see "result" is showing path of the image properly and in target I see src which is textbox name where path has to insert.

Problem is path is not inserting meaning in the src id textbox. Meaning **target.value = result;** is not working. Anyone tell me whats wrong please?

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "none",
    theme: "advanced",

    plugins: 'autoresize, save,preview,table,paste,insertdatetime,autolink,lists,spellchecker,style,inlinepopups,preview,xhtmlxtras,wordcount,searchreplace,directionality,visualchars,advhr,advimage,advlink,iespell,media,contextmenu,noneditable,nonbreaking,template',

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,bullist,numlist,|,styleselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,preview,|,insertfile,insertimage",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,advhr,template,|,ltr,rtl",
    theme_advanced_buttons4: "",

    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing: true,

    theme_advanced_resize_horizontal: false,

    file_browser_callback: "fileBrowserCallBack",


});

    function fileBrowserCallBack(field_name, url, type, win) {
    var connector = "../../filemanager/browser.html?Connector=connectors/php/connector.php";
    var enableAutoTypeSelection = true;

    var cType;
    tinyfck_field = field_name;
    tinyfck = win;

    switch (type) {
        case "image":
            cType = "Image";
            break;
        case "flash":
            cType = "Flash";
            break;
        case "file":
            cType = "File";
            break;
    }

    if (enableAutoTypeSelection && cType) {
        connector += "&Type=" + cType;
    }

    window.open(connector, "tinyfck", "modal,width=600,height=400");
}
```

**Below is the screen shot**

[image: fck filemanager with TinyMCE]

Comment: what do you mean with "textbox"?

Comment: @thariama ,  I mean Image URL textbox when we open image popup model.

Comment: can you show us what the variable target holds when given to fileBrowserCallBack and what value return has before assigning it to target.value  ?

Comment: @thariama , Thanks for the reply. Once I select the image from model the result is ../Content/UserImages/imagename.jpg like that. But its not setting in the Image URL textbox. I noticed that Image URL is lossing focus once model popup open. Any idea?

Comment: @thariama , Do you have any code to share?

Comment: i suggest you use firebug or firebug lite and use console.log(target); to output the contents to console

Comment: @thariama , This is exactly what I get in result "/Content/userfiles/image/Hydrangeas.jpg" and target I see "src" but in debuger after target.value = result; I see value undefined.

Comment: @thariama , console.log(target); is showing src which is id of the Image Url textbox . but console.log(target.value); is undefined.

Comment: what is "src id textbox"? where did you place console.log(target.value); ?

Comment: @thariama , in TinyMCE you have Insert/Edit Image Model Popup once you open it will have tabs and on general tab you have Image Url inputbox which has Id "src" . I placed console.log(target.value); in Firebug console right side panel which enable you to run commands.

Comment: sry, i do not understand

Comment: @thariama , I have updated the post. See the screen shot please